# SPA - handling DTOs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, webapi

I want to implement SPA based on any js framework in e.g. Angular JS. I already have many existing Web APIs with information that I need to show on app. I have to add 1 more that will manage new information. New one will reference to other DTOs. My question is, better approach is to call APIs and compile DTO on web app or call APIs in new API merge all data and create GET method with ready object.

**First** approach from web site perspective:

```
Call (I know userId - based on logged in user [in this example = 1])

/get/order/{userId}
{
UserId: 1
Products:{1,2}
}

based on that call:

/get/user/1
{
FirstName: test,
LastName: test
}

/get/product/1
{
Price: 10,
Name: Test
}

/get/product/2
{
Price: 100,
Name: Test2
}
```

merge all data in Angular Js Web

**Second** approach from web site perspective:

Merge everything on Order Web API

```
Call:

/get/ordermerged/{userId}
{
   FirstName: test,
   LastName: test
   Products:
   {
      {
         Price: 10,
         Name: Test
      },
      {
         Price: 100,
         Name: Test2
      }
   }
}
```

I attach screenshot to better overview.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

It's a trade-off between reusability and specialization. With reusability comes the obvious advantage - you may end up having to do less work. With specialization comes the advantage that your front end can consume the API as is. With specialization you'll also only ever load the data you actually need, whereas with many separated API's there might be redundant data and perhaps slightly more overhead.

I don't really think there's a notion of one approach being better than the other. It all depends on whether it's worth it for your specific situation. I'd argue that you should pick an approach per case. If some endpoints aren't really being reused anyway, you might as well create a "merged"/specialized version, where you get everything in one call. In other parts of your application, you may have endpoints that are more reusable and so you stick with them, and do a bit more "processing" client side.

Regarding performance (a single API call vs. multiple) the HTTP/2 protocol might give a small nudge in favor of multiple smaller API endpoints.

Whether one approach is better than the other for Angular specifically, doesn't really matter. Angular doesn't care. :-)

Comment: I consider also that 1st one is better because of that service should be single responsibility and when I will merge it in Order Web Api then it depends on other ones. What do you think about this?

Comment: It all depends on the context in which it is used. In your above example, I probably wouldn't merge everything into a single call. But I might merge the order information and product data into a single API endpoint to be called and then retrieve the user information in a separate call.